# Jackson in Android

Tags: android, jackson

I have this json string

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "subCategoryData": {
                "currentUserFollowed": false,
                "_id": "52cecd482505747925000000",
                "pic": "url_pic",
                "name": "Fine Dining                          ",
                "Data": [
                    {
                        "category": {
                            "_id": "52cecd482505747925000000",
                            "name": "Fine Dining"
                        },
                        "rating": 0,
                        "branches": [
                            {
                                "distance": 32.565917246528002,
                                "_id": "5416880d2505740b2d000001",
                                "name": " Restaurant"
                            }
                        ],
                        "name": "Terra Prime",
                        "currentUserFollowed": false,
                        "offers": [],
                        "isActive": 1,
                        "logo": "http://img.anthiss.com/brand/logos/mlarge-4cd905677bd9b6096316ca5f28357f6b.jpg",
                        "_id": "540d765f250574d94d00003d",
                        "nearestBranchDistance": 32.565917246528002
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "subCategoryData": {
                "currentUserFollowed": false,
                "_id": "52ea4c57250574c42200001c",
                "pic": "url_pic",
                "name": "Chinese Food                 ",
                "Data": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this classes I used to parse json:

```
public class SubCategoryData implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String pic;
    private boolean currentUserFollowed;


    public SubCategoryData() {
    }
}
```

But The list was returned contains List of SubCategoryData,

And all parameters in SubCategoryData are null

Comment: Do you have setter methods or a `@JsonCreator`?

Comment: yes I have setter and getter for all parameters, 

and I put this annotations above class
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE)